# stream stdout causes RAM usage to increase dramatically

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use `spawn` to run a command that runs constantly (Not supposed to stop) and it transmits data to its output. The problem is that RAM usage of the node app increases constantly.
After multiple tests, I could reach to following part of code that reproduces the problem, even though the functions are almost empty:

```
const runCommand = () => {

    const command = 'FFMPEG COMMAND HERE';
    let ffmpeg = spawn(command, [], { shell: true });

    ffmpeg.on('exit', function(code) { code = null; });

    ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function (data) { data = null; });

    ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) { data = null; });

};
```

I get the same problem with following:

```
const runCommand = () => {

    const command = 'FFMPEG COMMAND HERE';
    let ffmpeg = spawn(command, [], { shell: true });

    ffmpeg.on('exit', function(code) { code = null; });

    ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function (data) { data = null; });

    ffmpeg.on('spawn', function () {
       ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/dev/null'));
    });
};
```

The important part is, when I delete `function (data) {}` from `ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {});` the problem goes away. Type of received data is `buffer` object. I think the problem is with that part.

**The problem also appears when spawn pipes out the data to another writable (even to /dev/null).**

**UPDATE:** After hours of research, I found out that it's something related to spawn output and stream backpressure. I configured FFMPEG command to send chunks less frequently. That mitigated the problem (Increasing less than before). But memory usage still increasing.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen `spawn` pipes received data from FFMPEG to stdout. I'm not sure there's an `ffmpeg.on("data", ...)` event. How can I know what events are emitting from `spawn` object?

Comment: @Heiko Theißen adding `ffmpeg..on("data", function(data) {...})` didn't help

Comment: `ffmpeg.stdio` is an array containing all the pipes used by `ffmpeg`. Are there more than three (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`)?

Comment: @Heiko Theißen `ffmpeg.stdio` gives an array of 3 large objects like `<ref *1> Socket {...}`. So I guess the answer is yes, only 3.

Comment: If it's only three, then they are `stdin` (input), `stdout` and `stderr`. And you already consume `stdout` and `stderr`. So this does not explain the problem you observe. Sorry.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen When I delete the stdout function like `ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', null);` problem disappears. If you've no guess it's fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure it's the memory of the `node` process that increases and not the memory of the `spawn` subprocess? Notice that if you're not consuming the stdout stream, the ffmpeg process probably simply blocks so nothing is happening.

Comment: Try making a heap snapshot and inspecting where the data comes from

Comment: @Bergi I went for testing after your comment. Yes. Setting stdout function to `null` caused the command to abort. But is memory usage of a sub process count as node app memory usage??

Comment: I don't know, how were you measuring it?

Comment: @Bergi I use PM2. `pm2 status app.js` tells memory usage of the app. Can it be the case that `.on('data',...` function runs too much and keeps incoming data in memory until GC comes in?

Comment: "*The problem appears when spawn pipes out the data to another writable*" - that makes more sense, and @WolverinDEV might be onto something. So "*I could reach to following part of code that reproduces the problem, even though the functions are almost empty*" is wrong, it needs more code than `data = null` to cause the problem? Then please add the code of how you are piping/writing the data into another stream.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Updated the question. I'm sure it's something with piping and buffer memory. But I couldn't figure it out exactly. I'm gonna test @ WolverinDEV solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the `ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {});` line the problem fades away, but just partially because ffmpeg keeps on writing in the stdout and may eventually stop, waiting for the stdout to be consumed. For example, MongoDB has this "pause until stdout is empty" logic.

[If you are not going to process the stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio), just `ignore` it with this:

```js
const runCommand = () => {
    const command = 'FFMPEG COMMAND HERE';
    let ffmpeg = spawn(command, [], { shell: true, stdio: "ignore" });
    ffmpeg.on('exit', function(code) { code = null; });
};
```

This will make the spawned process to *dump* the stdout and stderr so there's no need to be consumed. Is the correct way, as you don't need to waste CPU cycles and resources reading a buffer that you are going to discard. Take into account that although you just add a one liner to read and discard the data, livuv (the nodejs IO manager, among other things) does more complex things to read this data.

Still, I'm pretty sure that you are facing this bug: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5145

It also seems that if you output too much logs, pm2 can't handle writing them to the output files as fast as needed, so reducing the log output can fix the problem: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1126#issuecomment-996626921

Comment: Thanks. I can't omit stdout and stderr cause I need them. The problem appears when spawn pipes out the data to another writable (even to `/dev/null`). Without piping the output or `on data` event, there's no problem.

Comment: I mean when I consume piped data, problem still exists.

Comment: @SoroushBgm Then try to run the process without pm2 as I think that is the culprit of your problem. Just read the last link in the question which is a GitHub issue. There's more people with a problem like yours. Maybe switching nodejs versions or pm2 versions can fix the problem.

Comment: Let me test and I'll notify you.

Comment: @SoroushBgm It also seems that if you output too much logs, pm2 can't handle writing them to the output files as fast as needed, so reducing the log output can fix the problem: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1126#issuecomment-996626921

Comment: I ran my app via pure node and logged memory usage every 10 seconds. It's not related to PM2. Rss still increasing.

Comment: I let my app to work more time, till now. With pure node memory increases but stays at some point (Not going further). It might be PM2 problem. I will add updates.

Comment: Last update: Problem exists with or without pm2

Comment: @SoroushBgm oh what a pity... thank you for the follow up btw.

Comment: @SoroushBgm "*The problem appears when spawn pipes out the data to another writable (even to `/dev/null`).*" - please add that to your question, it's vital information! Since that is not what the code shown in the question does.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you need the stdout output `stdio: "ignore"` is not an option.
Depending on what you're doing with the data you're receiving you may receive more data than you can handle. Therefore buffers build up filling your memory.

A possible solution will be to pause and resume the stream when data builds up too much.

```js
ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   ffmpeg.stdout.pause();
   doSomethingWithDataAsyncWhichTakesAWhile(data).finally(() => ffmpeg.stdout.resume());
});
```

When to pause and resume the stream highly depend on the factor how you handle the data.

Using in combination with a writeable (which when I'm not mistaken your're doing):

```js
ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   if(!writeable .write(data)) {
      /* We need to wait for the 'drain' event. */
      ffmpeg.stdout.pause();
      writeable .once('drain', () => ffmpeg.stdout.resume());
   }
});
```

`writeable.write(...)` returns false if the stream wishes for the calling code to wait for the 'drain' event to be emitted before continuing to write additional data; otherwise true. [source](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#writablewritechunk-encoding-callback).

If you're ignoring this you'll end up building up buffers in memory.
This *might* be the cause of your problem.

PS: As side note:
At least on unix systems when the output buffer of stdout has been filled and not been read (e.g. by pausing the stream) the application which writes to stdout will hang until there is space to write into. In case of ffmpeg this is not an issue and intended behaviour. But it's just something to be mindful of.